# CSS does not update automatically in Flask unless you do a hard reload

Tags: css, flask, caching, reload

#### Are there any solutions to disable Web Caching with HTML/JS/etc. that will solve the problem in both desktop and mobile browsers?

Comment: Hi DarkHouse, what do you mean with "full reload"?

Comment: i meant "hard reload" (shift + refresh(cmd + R)).

Answer (score 0):

The default maximum age of files in Flask is 12 hours, in order to force a no-caching policy app-wide, you can insert this line in your `app.py`:

```
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
```

This would be an example of your final result:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Differently, to disable caching within a single route, configure your response headers before sending the response itself:

```
resp.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
resp.headers["Cache-Control"] = "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public"
resp.headers["Expires"] = '0'
```

Of course, both solutions are not appropriate in a production server, however might help you during development.